# Detect removed TestStep

Tags: opentap-proj

Is it possible to detect the event when a TestStep is removed from the TestPlan?
[Remove TestStep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtnqX.png)

Comment: I don't know Keysight, so I probably can't help, but your question lacks a lot of details. What do you mean by "detect"? Detect in what way? Manually/automatically? And how is C# relevant? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

When the TestPlan Steps object changes the OnPropertyChanged event if thrown. You could watch that:
https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap/-/blob/master/Engine/TestPlan.cs#L36